# body split javascript email body

Tags: javascript

If I wanted to capture the following "DATALINER" from the line below, how could I do that?

> 1180328 101252 RPG0907 **710494/PRODUCTION/DATALINER** Msg: CI300R 18200 decimal-data error in field (C G S D F).Cause . . . . . : The RPG program CI300R in library OBJECT found a decimal-da

I currently have the following.

```
var jobName = body.split('/')[2];
```

While it is splitting properly, it's also including everything after DATALINER.

Comment: Hint: Split again on space.

Comment: Or use `indexOf(' ')` and use the position found to take the substring.

Comment: this line format always will be same or differ?

Answer (score 0):

if your line format always remain same, then you can get DATALINER by again split by space

```
var jobName = body.split('/')[2].split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var text = '1180328 101252 RPG0907 710494/PRODUCTION/DATALINER Msg: CI300R 18200 decimal-data error in field (C G S D F).Cause . . . . . : The RPG program CI300R in library OBJECT found a decimal-da';

var jobName = text.split('/')[2].split(' ')[0];
```